# Why can't I call startActivity on a manually instantiated Activity?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I just have a question on this exception. I have already fixed the code but I didn't know why I couldn't use my original way.

```
public class Login extends Activity
{
    EditText account, password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        account = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.account);
        password = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.password);

        Button_Listener listener = new Button_Listener();
        Button login = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.login);
        login.setOnClickListener(listener);
        Button reset = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.reset);
        reset.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    class Button_Listener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        Login l = new Login();

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.login:
                    if(account.getText().toString().equals("kenny"))
                    {
                        if(password.getText().toString().equals("12345"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Welcome",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent go = new Intent();
                            go.setClass(Login.this,MainMenu.class);
                            l.startActivity(go);   // NullPointerException here
                            Login.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter,R.anim.exit);
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Account or Password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Account or Password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.reset:
                    account.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I get a `NullPointerException` on the commented line? When I used `Login.this`, I didn't get this exception.

In addition to this question, why did I not get any value if I do `String name = account.getText().toString();` for the listener?

Comment: You never **ever** want to manually instantiate an activity

Comment: @TimCastelijns - looks like the button listener is an inner class. Couldn't `Login.this.startActivity` be used?

Comment: @cricket_007 The preferred way would be the following. `v.getContext().startActivity(go)`. Not sure why that hasn't been suggested yet.

Comment: I could used but im just wondering why couldn't I instantiate the class and use it.

Comment: Sorry about the dispute guys. My original question was that why wouldn't Android let me just use the instantiated object (referencing the Login, extending Activity, a subclass of Context) instead of using Login.this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this method fails is because you cannot just instantiate an activity and use it like it's an activity within android.

To explain: This `nullPointerException` is being thrown due to the `ActivityThread` not being set within your activity. This is an internal, private field that is normally set when an activity's `attach` method is called (**note:** this is not `onAttach` but the private method `attach`).

This is in turn called by a couple of other subsystems like the `ActivityThread` and `LocalActivityManager`, all of which you don't have direct control of; however, are called when you properly start activities.

Essentially, if you want to call `startActivity(Activity)` you should make sure you're calling it from something that is or extends `Context` and is an active part of the android lifecycle (such as `Login.this` activity instance which is already properly instantiated and being managed by android).

---

In short, the technique you're currently using (`Login.this`) is a correct way to do it.

In the future, depending on where/how you define the class, it is also correct to pass a context as an argument to a constructor of a class and use that context there if need be.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help mate :) and Happy New Year :)